# Preview a document (ie. excel/pdf) designed for any Mobile phone on my desktop PC?

Tags: mobile, document, mobile-phones, mobile-devices

Is there any free software or is there anyway to preview how a document will look once on the mobile device. So for example, a rendering engine for a Blackberry or Android etc. This way I can make my documents tailored to specific devices without having the phones.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would depend on the sort of document you were trying to create, and also what software on the phone is opening the document. There are a few different PDF readers on Android that I've used. On Blackberry, I believe the most common document reader is Documents to Go. In my opinion, a PDF is a terrible way to view content on a mobile device.

With that said, what I would do is download the SDKs for each of the platforms. They include an emulator that you can use that runs the OS in a virtual machine.